# Drupal 7. Dynamic node categorization

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, taxonomy

Say i use taxonomies.

vocabulary 1 contains terms referring to product category (categories).

vocabulary 2 contains terms referring to product output power (output power).

All products fall under a category, but not all products fall under a size.

Size, apart from being an entire vocabulary is a product attribute which should be activated if certain category is selected. (eg: selecting "car audio" will give the option of "output power". Selecting "netbooks" won't trigger that attribute, but rather some other as "screen resolution".)

How can this be accomplished? (using taxonomies or not)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Conditional Fields Module](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields).

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between
>   fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for
>   editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the
>   right condition.